# Network access and certificates

Tags: windows, security, networking

Could not access the network after importing a certificate.

The error is :The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved after the certificate was imported to the right folder.
Did not know that the certificate store location was equally important.

Should have placed the certificate under "Trusted Root Certificates".

[image]